# Searching for name in dataGridView through more then one table in C#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview

I have a browse button witch browses 5 different tables into `DataGridView`. I have a `scrollBar` to go through them. Now I need to make a search `TextBox` and if I write in it something like "Milk" it automatically finds all tables witch contain that name/word e.x. there were 5 tables to go through but now only 3, because only 3 contain word milk. Here is my code witch searches only in 1 table (I only got that far). Thank you!

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Prece LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any data-relations set in the gridView between the tables? How do you store that datasource? Why do you iterate on the gridview and not on the database?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Your gridViews here
     var gridList = new List<DataGridView>() { yourGrid1, yourGrid2};

     foreach(DataGridView dv in gridList)
     {
         dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Prece LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
     }
}
```

Add your `DataGridViews` to the List and let it iterate through them. You just have to handle how to output it then.

Note that I havn't edited your searching-method in here. I've just added the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one DataGridView and all DataTables are same

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Prece LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);

            DataTable dtMain=dv.ToTable().Copy();

            dv = new DataView(dt2);
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Prece LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
            dtMain.Merge(dv.ToTable());
            dv = new DataView(dt3);
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Prece LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
            dtMain.Merge(dv.ToTable());

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtMain;
        }
```